# How to program 2 function C button in calculator?

Tags: android, button, calculator

I'm a beginner in Android Studio, and I want to make a C button in calc with 2 functions. 
How do I do that on one tap the C button erases only one number, and on hold erase all numbers in TextView?

```
 findViewById(R.id.btnClear).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtScreen.setText("");  // Clear the screen
            // Reset all the states and flags
            lastNumeric = false;
            stateError = false;
            lastDot = false;
```

Comment: A C button as subject? What do you have in mind?

Comment: go through this it help you in logic http://www.hackpundit.com/android-tutorial-simple-calculator-app/

Comment: divide the number with 10 and put **quotient** in the textView again ...It remove last digit from your number .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an onClickListener and onLongClickListener to achieve this.

```
cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String currentText = textView.getText().toString();
            if(currentText.length >= 2){
                currentText = currentText.substring(0, currentText.length - 2);
            }else{
                currentText = "";
            } 
            textView.setText(currentText);
        }
 }); 



cButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            textView.setText("");
            return true;
        }
 });
```

Comment: The extra `else` branch solves the issue when having only one remaining `char`. @Jurica, use this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in to the `onClick()` and `onLongPress()` methods?

```
cancelButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            myTextView.setText("");
            return true;
        }
    });

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeOneCharacter();
        }
 });

private void removeOneCharacter()
{
    String textViewValue = myTextView.getText().toString();
    if (textViewValue != null && textViewValue.length >= 2)
    {
        myTextView.setText(textViewValue.substring(0, textViewValue.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

The `onClick()` method removes on `char` from the `TextView` at a time. The `onClick()` method however removes the entire `String` from the `TextView` but only considering if there is already 2 or more characters to prevent an `Exception` from occurring due to the upper-bound of the substring.

An improvement here could be to add another if function that checks the character length within the Long press and performs a clear if there is only one character remaining.

Comment: LongPress work's fine when I added 'txtScreen.setText("");', but onClick not.

Comment: @Jurica What was your value in the `TextView` when you did a click?

Comment: @Jurica This implementation will not remove a character when only 1 character was entered. Look at my answer below how to tackle this.